# Regex to Match #Comment Not Working Correctly

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression which will detect the following type of comment:

- Begins with a single `#` and continues until the end of the line
- Will treat any escaped `#` (`\#`) as ordinary text (thus, it will not make anything subsequent to it a comment if it wasn't one already)

Using [this tool](http://www.regexr.com/), I came up with the following regex to achieve this:

```
(?!\\)(#(.*)\n)
```

Using it in global mode, I tested it on the following input text, which is pretty self-explanatory:

```
#This comment should be caught, and any embedded #s or escaped \#s should also be
While none of this line this should be \#\#\#
```

Now, the matches for that regex are:

- The entire first line
- Everything on the second line starting from the first `#` but not including the `\` before it

Obviously, this is too much - nothing on that second line should be captured. What should I change to make it work how I want it to?

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's because you don't have `\n` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?<!\\)#.*
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<!\\)` asserts that what precedes is not a backslash.
- `#` matches a hash
- `.*` matches to the end of the line

See the matches in the **[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pS9tI3/1)**

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)